# V - slot, can't style or access it

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, v-slot

I add the v-flip on my nuxt webpage. So my template looks like this:

```js
<div class="about__cards">
 <vue-flip class="about__single-card" active-click width = "350px" height="450px">
    <template v-slot:front>
        <p class="about__title">Stacks</p>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:back>
        <h4>My stacks</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>Javascript</li>
          <li>Css</li>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>Vue</li>
          <li>Nuxt</li>
        </ul>
      </template>
    </vue-flip>
...
```

This was my styling:

```css
.about__cards{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  /* background-color: transparent; */
}
.about__single-card{
  border:1px red solid;
  border-radius: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front{
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* line-height: 448px; */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
 /*  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-end; */
}
```

I put front because when inspecting the element I saw that was given that class. All all seems working. Then I realized that I haven't scoped the style so was messing with other pages. I did, restart the server and now it's not working anymore the styling of the v-slot. But If I go to inspect the element and I go to the `"front"`class that was pre-given I can change it there... I read that you can style v-slots, but before I did it so I am kind of confused. What I am missing here?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because scoped styles are "scoped" by using component unique id as part of the selector.

If you inspect your app, you will see things like this (`1d328d7a` is the **uid**)

```html
<div
  data-v-1d328d7a=""
  class="field-input-wrapper"
...
```

```css
.field-input-wrapper[data-v-1d328d7a] {
  ...
```

In order to bypass this, you can use [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) like this

```css
.about__single-card >>> .front{
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```